# Create vector of attributes for each row in data frame

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, attributes, row

Assume that we have the data frame

```
attr1 | attr2
----- | -----
  1   |   2
  2   |   0
```

Now, for each row in our data frame, I would like to create a vector that contains `attr1` and `attr2`. This vector shouldn't be a string representation, but an actual vector that contains those numbers.

The desired result would be this:

```
attr1 | attr2 |   vec   |
----- | ----- | ------- | 
  1   |   2   | c(1, 2) |
  2   |   0   | c(2, 0) |
```

How can this be done in R?

Comment: If you need a string element, then use `paste` i.e. `df1$vec <- do.call(paste, c(df1, sep=", "))`

Comment: I would prefer that attr1 and attr2 were included in the solution, as every row contains other 'irrelevant' data (not in this simplified example)

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 <- data.frame(attr1 = c(1,2),attr2 = c(2,0))
df1
#   attr1 attr2
# 1     1     2
# 2     2     0

df1$vec <- noquote(paste("c(",paste(df1$attr1,df1$attr2,sep=","),")",sep=""))
df1
#   attr1 attr2    vec
# 1     1     2 c(1,2)
# 2     2     0 c(2,0)
```

Checking Class of each column

```
sapply(df1,class)
#      attr1     attr2       vec 
#  "numeric" "numeric" "noquote"
```

Note: The `vec` column is actually a string, so just removed quotes using `noquote()` function.

If you want just the numbers to be together, still going to be character vector, but without a `c()` in the column

```
df1 <- data.frame(attr1 = c(1,2),attr2 = c(2,0))
df1
#   attr1 attr2
# 1     1     2
# 2     2     0

df1$vec <- paste(df1$attr1,df1$attr2, sep=",")
df1
#   attr1 attr2 vec
# 1     1     2 1,2
# 2     2     0 2,0
```

Checking Class of each column

```
sapply(df1,class)
#     attr1       attr2         vec 
# "numeric"   "numeric" "character"
```

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, but I don't want them as a string, I want them as actual vectors.